# CSS Layout and <body> tag not working together and passing validation

Tags: php, html, css, validation

Sorry for the really dumb title but I dont know how else to phrase it.

Well I have my `index.php` which provides a nice *frame* layout for my HTMl using CSS and `divs`. Each page i.e the *header*, *navigation bar*, *footer* etc. are added in the `div` via PHP `include(..)`.

Here is my `index.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <style type="text/css" media="screen">

            html, body{
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0 auto;
                height: 100%;
            }

            #header {
                width: 100%;
                height: 15%;
                background-color: green;
            }

            #navbar {
                float: left;
                width: 20%;
                height: 70%;
                background-color: red;
            }

            #content {
                float: right;
                width: 80%;
                height: 70%;
                background-color: blue;
            }
            #footer {
                clear: both;
                width: 100%;
                height: 15%;
                background-color: yellow;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header"> 
            <?php 
                include("header.html"); 
            ?>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar"> 
            <?php 
                include("nav.php"); 
            ?>
        </div>
        <div id="content"> 
            <?php 
                include("home.html"); 
            ?>
        </div>
        <div id="footer"> 
            <?php 
                include("footer.php"); 
            ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now look here in `<body>` tag of `index.php`:

```
<div id="header"> 
    <?php 
        include("header.html"); 
    ?>
</div>
```

this piece will of course add my `header.html` which looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type"
        content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"
        />
    </head>

    <body>
        <p align="center">TITLE PAGE</p>
    </body>

</html>
```

producing this:

[image]

See that white bar at the top of *TITLE PAGE*? Well thats not meant to be there...

And if I add anything to my actual `<body>` of  `header.html` i.e:

```
<body>
    Hello
    <p align="center">TITLE PAGE</p>
</body>
```

Notice how the white bar disappears and web browser does not have the scrollbar anymore? everything works just peachy - well besides that random text needed to clear the white bar:

[image]

So basically my question is why is this happening and how would I go about fixing it?

**UPDATE:**

Fixed white bar by setting

margin in header.html to 0 (+1 @Imperative):

```
<p align="center" style="margin: 0;">TITLE PAGE</p>
```

Now I would just like to know wether or not I am doing right by including DOCTYPE html header title etc tags each time I create a new html? Or should I only do this once in my index.php? If so than how would I make my header.html pass validation at http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Your header.html contains <html><body> etc tags, which are then put inside your page. Isn't that invalid html?

Comment: @MariaIoannidou Not sure I thought each new file would have to have the *html* *header* *title* and body tags or it wont pass the validation at http://validator.w3.org/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are including a whole html page into your page, with `<head>` definitions etc..

The header.html should look like this `<p align="center">TITLE PAGE</p>` only.
Same applies for the other includes.

Comment: Ooo I thought each new file would have to have the *html* *header* *title* and body tags or it wont pass the validation at http://validator.w3.org/? So only my `index.php` will have the *html* *head* etc tags?

Comment: *The header.html should look like this <p align="center">TITLE PAGE</p> only* I changed it to that and still same output

Comment: Correct, <head> and <body> only appreas once per html file.

Comment: Once per html file? but header.html is its own file hence the tags appear there too? Or am I getting it wrong?

Comment: the white bar originates from the <p> element, which has a default margin to top and bottom. set it to zero and the white bar will disappear, see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SeV6D/1/ furthermore i ask you to look into the html source code and analyse the presence of <html> tags.

Comment: +1 thank you it is now working with the margin set... Last question if I wanted to separate the <p> into its own file as to not take up to much space in my index.php how would that separate file look? Would it only include the doctype and the <p> or should it use html and head tags too?

Comment: it would only contain the <p> tag

Comment: And to validate I would use a template with the necessary tags in order to pass valiadation?

Answer (score 1):

do not add anything in BODY if you are using include, just write down what you need without BODY, by including another BODY you just mess everything around.

your header.php should look like this

```
<center>TITLE PAGE</center>
```

DONT ADD `<p>` that is messing everything.

Comment: I see so I would still keep my html tags etc in header.html and only remove the body? Because I removed body but still the same

Comment: remove the '<p>' and everything is gonna be ok!

Comment: Thank you with your update my code is now working +1... But I must ask... now that my header.html looks like that: `<center>TITLE PAGE</center>` it doesnt pass validation on http://validator.w3.org/ why is this?

Comment: Seems setting the <p> margin to 0 helped as said by @Imperative. But Im still confused as to wether or not doctype html tags etc should be included in my header.html or it wont pass validation...

Comment: remove the <html> <body> <head> tags from the included file IF these tags were already declared in the parent file. Meaning that one PAGE can have only ONE pair of <html> <body> <head> tags.

Comment: thanks for the help mate. And Im guesing to validate I should just have an empty template with html and header tags in which Ill place the html in order to validate

Comment: I don't know much about validator, I'm using DW and after I removed those tags it was valid.

Comment: DOCTYPE must be included only once in your index page.